# Nullable "scalar navigation properties" in EF 4.0: Mapping a non-nullable column from a separate database table to a nullable scalar entity property?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, nullable, non-nullable

Using Entity Framework version 4.0 (or any other version that is compatible with .NET 4.0), I want to map this existing relational database schema:

[image: Relational database schema]

to this logical object model:

[image: Logical object model]

which I have tried setting up as follows: (I hope the German captions won't be too disorienting.)

[image: Entity Framework's mapping details for the <code>Foo</code> entity and settings for its <code>B</code> property]

Entity Framework gives me this error:

> *Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments …: Non-nullable column `FooBs.B` in table `FooBs` is mapped to a nullable entity property.*

In the logical model, `B` ought to be nullable. However, in the database, it isn't, because it resides in a separate table. (I like to avoid nullable database columns.) It only becomes nullable when `Foos` and `FooBs` are joined (due to the 1:0..1 cardinality).

How can I fix my mapping, without altering either the database schema or the object model?

---

> **P.S.:** I also tried this EF 6.0 code-first mapping:
>
> ```
> protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
> {
>     modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
>     .HasKey(f => f.Id)
>     .Property(f => f.Id).HasColumnName("FooId").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
>     modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(f => {
>         f.Property(_ => _.A);
>         f.ToTable("Foos");
>     }).Map(f => {
>         f.Property(_ => _.B);
>         f.ToTable("FooBs");
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> But this doesn't work either: When reading from the database, EF ignores all records for which there is no sub-record in `FooBs`; when writing to the database, it attempts to insert `NULL` into `FooBs.B` for all `Foo` that have their `B` property set to `null`.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140851/entity-framework-1-to-0-1-relationship-in-single-entity#comment35496861_23140851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a rather "dirty" solution that should work. It would require some code changing but would leave your `Foo` entity with field `A` and `B`.

`Foo` class:

```
class Foo {
   [Key]
   public int FooId { get; set; }
   public int A { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public int? B {
      get {
         return FooB == null ? null : FooB.B;
      }
      set {
         if(value == null) {
            FooB = null;
         } else {
            if(FooB == null)
               FooB = new FooB();
            FooB.B = (int)value;
         }
   public virtual FooB FooB{ get; set; }
}
```

And mapped to database class `FooB`:

```
 class FooB {
    [Key, ForeignKey("FooId")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
 }
```

On side note - it seems like very strange way to add essentially single nullable column to a table, as there is no logical way where `FooB` could have more than one non-nullable column, that wouldn't result in deleting whole entity on setting columns value to null.

Another option is creating a database view that would behave like you want and map that to entity.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You say, "There is a … solution that should work." To your best knowledge, is this just *one* solution, or quite likely the only solution?

Comment: In general it seems like a very strange use case - there might be other solutions, but I can't think of another one.

Comment: Thanks. Not so strange: As I understand it, this is simply a case of database normalization that goes beyond 3NF. I'd expect an ORM to be able to deal with this. Since your solution should work (esp. with some combination of `partial class`) and is the only response I got, I'll accept your answer. Many thanks for your suggestion!