# Entity Framework 1 to 0..1 relationship in single entity

Tags: entity-framework

**Scenario**

I have a scenario where I defined a 1 to 1 relationship for two tables in the DB within a single entity. I did so by using the following mapping (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SingleEntity>()
            .Map(map =>
            {
                map.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.MetaData1,
                    p.MetaData2,
                    p.Foo,
                    p.Bar
                });

                map.ToTable("EntityInfo");

            })
            .Map(map =>
            {
                map.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.BinaryArray,
                    p.ContentType,
                    p.FileName
                });

                map.ToTable("EntityDocument");

            });
```

This gave me a single entity in the domain but saved the data associated with this entity to two different tables. This is done so that the meta data on a document could be retrieved without the need to pull the entire binary of each document on a query.

This worked when the requirement was that Document Meta data would always have a document associated with it...then the requirements changed (as they are wont to do). Now we can have Meta data on a document that doesn't exist (yet).

**My Question**

I want to model the same entity with a 1 to 0..1 relationship ***without*** splitting the entity into two entities. Based on the searches I have done so far I am not sure it is possible to do this but if I am wrong (and I hope that I am) I would really prefer to have this object modeled as a single entity as it was before.

Any idea how to map this type of relationship in Entity Framework?

Comment: EF wants to materialize the whole entity. Is it a problem to start out with an empty document?

Comment: Well that is sort of the problem. The schema doesn't allow 'EntityDocument' records where the BinaryArray is null (NN) but the business rule is that they can be. So what was once a 1 to 1 relationship has become a 1 to 0..1 relationship. I feel the fields on the EntityDocument table should be changed to allow null values but my DBA disagrees.

Comment: I mean a document of zero length.

Comment: I see what you are saying and that is a creative way to approach it. I am sure that would have worked but I split the entities into two entities and then set up a 1 to 0..1 relationship between them.

Comment: @DigitalMoss: I recently asked a very [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137775/nullable-scalar-navigation-properties-in-ef-4-0-mapping-a-non-nullable-column) (I think). The responses it received (almost none) isn't too encouraging.

Comment: @Stakx: I am unable to comment there because I need more rep but the answer on that page is what I went with for my solution. In hindsight, unless an entity is a single primitive value (very rare) then it probably makes more sense for it to be a complex object as a property on the parent entity rather than 2+ primitive properties on the parent.